# Java Interface method supporting variable number of arguments with different types

Tags: java, interface

I would like to build an interface containing a method that can take a variable number of arguments of various types, something like as follows:

```
interface MyInterface {

   boolean myMethod(Object ...args); <--HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PASS ANY NUMBER OF PARMS OF ANY TYPE

}
```

In the concrete implementations of the interface, I would like to pass any number of params of any type as follows:

```
class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface {

   boolean myMethod(Student s, Course d) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Another implementation could be as follows:

```
 class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface {

   boolean myMethod(Department d) {
      ...
   }
}
```

In this regard, I have gone through a few posts here, but not getting any idea regarding how to do this. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have thought of the exact interface structure to be like below:

```
interface ConditionEvaluator {
     
     boolean evaluate(Object ...args);
     CondtionName getConditionName();
   }
```

One concrete implementation will look something like this:

```
class StudentEvaluator implements MyInterface {
  
    boolean evaluate(Student s, List<Course> courses) {
      ...
    }
  
    ConditionType getConditionType() {
       return ConditionType.STUDENT_PASSED;
    }
 }
```

To use this, I have thought that, I will create an enum map, containing ConditionType as key and concrete implementations as values as follows:

```
Map<ConditionType, MyInterface> conditionTypeMap;
```

Then from the caller method, was thinking of deriving appropriate implementation based on appropriate `ConditionType`.

Usage is somewhat like below,

I will have a factory class as follows:

```
@Component
public class ConditionEvaluatorFactory {

  private final Map<ConditionType, ConditionEvaluator> conditionEvaluatorMap;

  public ConditionEvaluatorFactory(List<ConditionEvaluator>
                                          conditionEvaluatorList) {
    Map<ConditionTyope, ConditionEvaluator> evaluatorMap =
        new EnumMap<>(ConditionEvaluator.class);
    for (ConditionEvaluator evaluator :
        conditionEvaluatorList) {
      evaluatorMap.put(evaluator.getConditionType(),
          evaluator);
    }
    this.conditionEvaluatorMap = evaluatorMap;
  }

  public ConditionEvaluator getEvaluator(ConditionType conditionType) {
    ConditionEvaluator evaluator = conditionEvaluatorMap
        .get(conditionType);
    if (evaluator == null) {
      throw new Exception("error message");
    }
    return evaluator;
  }
}
```

Caller class is as follows:

```
@component
class StudentUtil {

 @Autowired
 private ConditionEvaluatorFactory evaluatorFactory;

 public void callerFunc(Student s, List<Course> courseList) {
    boolean flag = evaluatorFactory.getEvaluator(ConditionType.STUDENT_PASSED).evaluate(s, courseList);
 ...
    
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the point of having the interface is? That is, are you going to have code where you have references to objects of type `MyInterface` and call `myMethod` on them?

Comment: This just isn't possible in Java I'm afraid. What would be your real-world usage of such a pattern though? That interface doesn't seem to have much purpose here.

Comment: How would any calling code be able to use an instance of `MyInterface` if the arguments are simply not defined in the interface and can be arbitrary.

Comment: @sp00m, Actually, I wanted to have a common interface that will have a single method taking different params and evaluate them to true/false. In my application, there are a few use cases to evaluate such conditions. That's why I thought of having a common interface and provide concrete implementation accordingly.

Now, as you said, it's not possible, I don't understand, what is the best way to do thus npw.

Comment: Can you give an example in your question of exactly what you mean? That is, write some code that would use the interface.

Comment: *"Actually, I wanted to have a common interface that will have a single method taking different params"* - you can have a common interface OR methods taking wildly different parameters. Both together simply makes no sense - if the methods have wildly different parameters they cannot share a common interface, they simply do not conform to a single interface, even in the literal interpretation, regardless of java.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now but check the Visitor pattern. If you have no answer by when I'll have some spare time, I'll post an example.

Comment: @Joy the arguments that you would pass (such as Student s, List<Course> c etc.) are they members of their respective classes (StudentEvaluator, DepartmentEvaluator etc.) or are they external parameters that the classes do not know about?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the params passed in evaluate() function of respective concrete class i.e. StudentEvaluator, DepartmentEvaluator etc. are external params.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that would use `conditionTypeMap`?

Comment: @Joy yes I see that, but where these parameters come from? Can you show an example of how you want to call this code (including the declaration and initialization of the arguments)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I have added initialization of the map as well as sample usage of the condition evaluations in the OP. I hope, it helps.

Comment: I don't see the value of the `ConditionEvaluatorFactory`. There is value in injecting a `ConditionEvaluator` in `StudentUtil`, but why not just inject a `StudentPassedEvaluator`, created as a an `@Bean` in your configuration. You must be creating a component like that anyway to supply the list of evaluators for the factory's constructor. Why not inject them where they are needed, and eliminate the factory *and* `MyInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from an important point: the reason why we have an `interface` which is implemented by multiple children classes is because all of these classes share *the same logic*, even if they follow a different implementation.

In your case, it doesn't look you can really have an interface (or at least, you cannot do it without having to accept a variable list of unknown types and cast them to static types at some point).

There really is no ideal solution for your problem, but I tried to make up something anyway.

If all your objective was to have a single point where you simply call an evaluator according to a condition you want to check, something you may do is to declare a class that holds a map of inputs:

```
public class Inputs {

    private final Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();

    public static Inputs builder() {
        return new Inputs();
    }

    public Inputs push(String key, Object value) {
        inputs.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public <T> T get(String key) {
        return (T) inputs.get(key); //<-- Unchecked cast, but somewhere you have to do it unfortunately
    }

}
```

Then, in the enumeration you had called `ConditionType`, add an `abstract` method that accepts an `Inputs` in parameter and returns a `boolean` as the result of the evaluation.

Once you do that, you can implement the special treatment inside each specific value of the enum:

```
public enum ConditionType {
    STUDENT_PASSED {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Inputs inputs) {
            Student student = inputs.get("student");
            List<Course> courses = inputs.get("courses");
            //do your logic with student and courses
            return false;
        }
    },
    DEPARTMENT_OPEN {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Inputs inputs) {
            Department department = inputs.get("department");
            //do your logic with department
            return false;
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean evaluate(Inputs inputs);
}
```

Like that, inside your utility classes, you will be able to do something like this:

```
public class EvaluationUtils {

    public void callerFunc(Student student, List<Course> courses) {
        Inputs input = Inputs.builder()
                .push("student", student)
                .push("courses", courses);
        boolean flag = ConditionType.STUDENT_PASSED.evaluate(input);
        //...
    }

    public void callerFunc(Department department) {
        Inputs input = Inputs.builder()
                .push("department", department);
        boolean flag = ConditionType.DEPARTMENT_OPEN.evaluate(input);
        //...
    }

}
```

The only advantage that I see in the above approach is that it avoids you to make checks and casts in each implementation.

Yet, it's not really different than declaring the interface as you originally thought (`boolean evaluate(Object...)`) and each implementation will get the arguments, check the size, the types and then proceed. But then again, your case simply doesn't sound like a case which can be factorized into an interface or any shared method.

Comment: this answer helped. Thanks a lot. One small thing, in the code snippet that you provided in the answer, I think, you have to typecast while getting values from the map by a key.

Comment: @Joy nope, I'm not using the get method of the map, but the get method of my class. In that get method I'm already inferring the type into the signature, so I don't need to cast. You can try that yourself to check :)

Comment: P.s. as I stated in the comment, unfortunately this solution needs to go through an unchecked cast to work. The only place where you perform the unchecked cast is inside the get method itself, but the rest of your code will work with statically-typed objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Generics are for. Define your interface thus:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {

    boolean myMethod(T arg);
}
```

Then your basic one-argument implementation would be:

```
class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface<Department> {

    boolean myMethod(Department d) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And your two-argument implemtation would need a holder class:

```
class CourseEnrollment {
    Student s; Course d;
}

class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface<CourseEnrollment> {

    boolean myMethod(CourseEnrollment ce) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he wants that, because the number of parameters may change for each implementation.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the question, because an instance for an unknown parameter type would have to be declared as `MyInterface<?>`, which makes it impossible to invoke the method on this instance.

Comment: @Izruo if you just use a raw type you can call it... But I don't think we understand what the OP is hoping for.

Comment: @tgdavies if I got it right, I think he wants an interface to call all the time ".myMethod(" with some parameters which vary, and according to what and how many these parameters are he wants to fall into the correct implementation. I think he wants a visitor pattern.

Comment: @tgdavies If you *have* to use a raw type to call the method, you could just get rid of the generics and instead use `Object` as parameter type, thus rendering the generics useless. You end up with less compiler warnings and the same functionality.

Comment: Well, then you can't override the parameter type in the subclasses, but I agree that this is a dead end, and perhaps a Visitor pattern is appropriate -- but I still don't understand the goal.